# Tense: John will prove to the world that Mahari was right

Tags: tense

I see a sentence without further context:

> John will prove to the world that Mahari was right.

I don't understand the meaning of that sentence.
Why does it say `Mahari was right`, instead of `Mahari is right`?

My reasoning is that:

> Mahari has been dead while John has this intention.

If Mahari is still alive, maybe the sentence would be:

> John will prove to the world that Mahari is right.

What do you think and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for *Mahari to be dead* as you say. The 'Was' there denotes the *action of Mahari* which happened *at a time in the past*, and some people thought that it was wrong.

Consider Mahari a Minister and some days before making a decision on some important issue in the country which made the opposition party think that it's wrong.

So, John will prove in the future that Mahari's action (in the past) was right.

Comment: I think this answer is right.  Although I would note that if he **is** dead, the past tense would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks VijayaRagavan. You give a clear explanation of my question.  @snailboat : Thank you for your additional remarks.